# Link Item in List View in textbox in other form

Tags: vb.net, forms, listview, hyperlink

I have trouble in coding in this area. I have a two forms. In the first form, i have list view that when i checked the checkbox, i will click the button to show the 2nd form and the 2nd form will show the item that i selected in first form.

but i have error like this: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index

This is my code:

```
'View Technicians Daily Task Code
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e _
                          As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    frm_pe.Show()
    Me.Close
    frm_pe.txtid.Text = ListView1.CheckedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text
    frm_pe.txtlname.Text = ListView1.CheckedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
    frm_pe.txtfname.Text = ListView1.CheckedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text
    frm_pe.txtmi.Text = ListView1.CheckedItems(0).SubItems(3).Text
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't close the first form until you have gathered the data you want, instead wait to close the form like this:

```
'View Technicians Daily Task Code
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e _
                      As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    frm_pe.Show()

    frm_pe.txtid.Text = ListView1.CheckedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text
    frm_pe.txtlname.Text = ListView1.CheckedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
    frm_pe.txtfname.Text = ListView1.CheckedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text
    frm_pe.txtmi.Text = ListView1.CheckedItems(0).SubItems(3).Text

    Me.Close
End Sub
```

OR

You can just hide the form, like this:

```
Me.Hide
```

Note: Hiding the form will still keep the form in memory, but make it invisible to the user.